# Variable used before being initialized with if statement

Tags: swift

It’s strange but when I want to run this code :

```
func test () {

var a: Int
let b = true
var c: Int

if b {
    a = 10
}

c = a * a

}
```

It says « variable a used before being initialized ».

So I need to implement else statement :

```
func test () {

var a: Int
let b = true
var c: Int

if b {
    a = 10
} else {
    a = 0 // will never be executed
}

c = a * a

}
```

It says logically that else will never be executed. But then why do they force me to implement else statement ?

Comment: To fix the problem, you might just want to make `a` an IUO (Implicitly Unwrapped Optional) if you can be certain what the values will be / which branch is called. Or a regular optional and coalesce the result if still `nil`.

Comment: Simply assign the variable an initial value, `var a = 0` (or given the code maybe use 10 as the initial value instead).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an initial value to the variable by declaring the variable as `Int()` it assigns the value `0` by default.

By making this line change everything works for me: `var a: Int` --> `var a = Int()`

```
func test() {
    var a = Int()
    let b = true
    var c: Int
    
    if b {
        a = 10
    }
    c = a * a
}
```

With the help of this you don't need to add `esle` part.

Answer (score 0):

as the previous response said, because of the `if b` `a` may not be initialised, the simplest solution is to just give `a` a default value, but if you don't want it to be changed after being initialised you can provide and `else` instead for example

```
func test () {

    let a: Int
    let b = true
    var c: Int

    if b {
        a = 10
    } else {
        a = 0
    }

    c = a * a    
}
```

You can see the `a` is defined as `let`, and once set in the `if` or `else` its value is set.